# Magento2: What are the complete steps to Install security Patchs in magento2

Tags: magento2, patches, installation, supee-9767

Can anyone please share the complete steps to Install & revert security Patches safely in magento2.

Comment: Patch SUPEE-9767 is not for Magento 2, Its for Enterprise Edition 1.9.0.0-1.14.3.2 and Community Edition 1.5.0.1-1.9.3.2

Comment: Oh right. i just checked. I will edit my question.